# Cons of Storing Incorrect Password Attempts (possibly as plain-text) in MySQL

Tags: php, security, authentication, passwords

As a security feature on a PHP website I am creating I plan to record password attempts in a table for a low traffic website. (Correct passwords are salted and stored with non reversible encryption.)

This is to temporarily and permanently in some cases block users and IPs based on their number of attempts within a time range and their location.

I plan to store incorrect usernames and passwords in plain text or with reversible (asymetric) encryption.

A user who has a typo in their username may have their correct password stored, so...

Is this an awful idea? If so, why and  what would you recommend? Reversible encryption?

I am inclined to store incorrect attempts as I am interested to see what incorrect passwords bots use to brute force so I can prevent their use.

(I currently block users from using the 100 most common passwords from the famous adobe hack along with a few others.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this is awful, for the reasons you stated but also because many users may have several passwords they always use and will try each of these if they can't remember their password.

Reversible encryption is not much better. Anyone with access to the passwords likely has access to whatever is doing the decryption and encryption.

I would advise against this altogether and rather try to encourage good passwords rather than preventing bad ones.

Comment: All users' passwords are of the same length (we generate passwords for the users). Would it matter if I then excluded passwords of that length from being stored? Still 100% against?

Comment: So users can't change their passwords? How are the passwords given to the users?

Comment: Most users do not have that privilege. Account Managers can set their own but not view others. Every 6 months we assign new passwords to users and physically hand them to them or their manager on paper as part of another system I have no control over.

Comment: That's not as bad imho then. However as you note, almost right passwords will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to see what incorrect passwords are used? Actually, it is sufficient to reject commonly used passwords without knowing what they are.

You can use commonly used one-way hash functions such as `bcrypt` and store the hash values. Against each hash value, keep a counter to indicate how frequently they are being used. All your operations, such as blocking the user, will be based on hashed passwords, not the plain ones.

Comment: Not a good idea as you'd need a static salt for this to work which means your password list can be easily cracked.

Comment: Correct passwords will use dynamic salts. If hash verification fails, only the wrong passwords are stored using static salt. Anyway, my answer is not relevant since others are saying the right approach is to use strong passwords.

Comment: This would give an attacker a list of passwords _not_ to try.

Comment: That's right. This is why this is not the right approach. I would go with the answer given by Jim.